# No sound on my inspiron 14 3000 series

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

This is my alsa info script output
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=8fa1ca353d9e49e9c2b5bbcc6f0bb2f2251c0c2c

After update my laptop suddenly lose it's sound. I've been tinkering with whatever command I found on google and other site that mention the same problem but none works. help please!!

Comment: Hello, how did you get the error message, and it seem that you're still running on 3.5 kernel, are you using a pre-installed Ubuntu? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: yeah i am using a pre-installed one. things just went wrong after this 200mb or so update yesterday, i've been tinkering a lot with command i found on websites with stated that it would fix the prob but its not. can u help me fix this error? just comment what output u need from me. thank you very much the ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS



its my first laptop that use linux so i am a bit confused.

Comment: Does your internal speaker is now called "Dummy output" in sound settings, and if you plug a headset to it, headphone still working? Can you run the [alsa-info script](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo) and paste the link [back to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/601427/edit)? Thanks

Comment: hmm nope. its still called built-in audio. havent tried headphone yet so i dont know. tried and this is the result

Comment: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=8fa1ca353d9e49e9c2b5bbcc6f0bb2f2251c0c2c

Comment: Your PulseAudio says `Daemon already running.` Please follow these instructions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log